# How do I change the application language in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I'm developing an application with ASP.NET 3.5 and I have read that the language that the application is shown in is the navigator's language.

Is there any way to choose the language of the application programmatically? For example, I want to see the application in English but my Internet Explorer is in Spanish.

The language is a user's preference stored in the database, so I need to change the language when the user logs in.

Comment: Non-programatic solution: In ie, go to tools->options and click the language button. Here you can add languages, and temporarilly move english to the top of the list, this changes the order of locals ie uses to choose the language to display. If there is an english version it will use it before the spanish, then when you're finished, move english down the stack.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you don't see the C# tag on my question, or maybe you don't understand my question.
I want to change my application's language, not the language of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class to set the culture for your executing environment.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to change your browser's accept language?  See http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/7b4a0825-28e2-4929-82f6-1feac4adb6f31033.mspx for instructions for IE 7 and IE 8.  The section you want is "To add a language to Internet Explorer"

Comment: No, I asking how to change programmatically the languague of my application.

Comment: You could have explained it more clearly.  Specifically mentioning Internet Explorer and its current language settings obviously makes people think your question is related to...Internet Explorer.  Hopefully, Kirtan's answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it in web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <globalization
    requestencoding="utf-8"
    responseencoding=" utf-8"
    fileencoding=" utf-8"
    culture="en-US"
    uiculture="en-US" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or at the page level:

```
<%@ Page Culture="en-US" UICulture="en-US" ResponseEncoding="utf-8"%>
```

Comment: The language is a user's preference. I have to take this preference from SQL Server and then change the application's language.

Comment: Okay, then you have to do it like Kirtan suggests... I only added this for completeness ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>` in `<system.web>` section of web.config.